# Asp.NET Webforms register.aspx validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, file-upload, webforms

I am developing a customised website using Visual Studio 2017. I have included Identity and so there are some provided pages to register or logon users. I am adapting the register page to allow a picture to be uploaded using the fileupload control (I have created a profile table and this will hold the extra data I want to capture). However when I do this the validation for the email is triggered when I submit, even though the email text box has data. I assume it might have something to do with the way the page is reloaded when the upload functionality takes place? I also want to add a checkbox and show additional fields if it is checked, using the CheckedChanged event to set Visible properties of the controls I want hidden.  I have seen that if I want to do this I need to set the AutoPostBack to true.
Code in register.aspx

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
    <p class="text-danger">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
    </p>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create a new account</h4>
        <hr />
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">User Name</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name is required." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm password</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                    CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The confirm password field is required." />
                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                    CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password and confirmation password do not match." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserPicture" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Upload your user picture</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UserPicture" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="userStatus" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Do you want to upload Artwork? If so check this box and once approved you will be able to do this.</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="userStatus" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" Checked=false OnCheckedChanged="userStatus_CheckedChanged" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ArtistIntro" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" ID="lblInfo" Visible="True">Please enter information about yourself as an artist</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ArtistIntro" CssClass="form-control" Visible="True" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

code in register.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using UHFinal.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace UHFinal.Account
{
    public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                //Insert a UserAccount record to save the additional details.
                //Also sets the userStatus. AP or UP, Artist Pending or User Pending

                string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["defaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into userAccount(UserID, userStatus, UserPicture, ArtistIntro) " +
                    "values(@userId, @userStatus, @UserPicture, @UserIntro)", conn);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", user.Id);
                if (userStatus.Checked == true) { 
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userStatus", "AP");
                    }
                else
                {
                    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userStatus", "UP");
                }
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPicture", "UserPics/" + UserPicture.FileName);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserIntro", ArtistIntro.Text);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    object returnObj = insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;    
                }
                conn.Close();


                signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);

                }

            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        protected void userStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userStatus.Checked == true)
            {
                ArtistIntro.Visible = true;
                lblInfo.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ArtistIntro.Visible = false;
                lblInfo.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: sorry, most of it is generated by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, I had left out the Email when creating the new ApplicationUser.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text, Email = Email.Text };
```